# Count distinct Customer ID meeting multiple criteria for a period of time

Tags: arrays, excel, countif

Trying to calculate the unique customers (distinct count of customer ID- numeric field) meeting the criteria listed below so that I can make a customer roll-forward which will stratify customers based on new business, expansion, contraction, churn for a month. I tried using the formula below but i am getting 1 instead a count of 10. (using excel on mac)

Criteria : **product family** = Digital Core, **final category** = new business , **customer start** = 4/30/2014 , **disposition** = include

`{=SUM(IF(AND("Digital Core"=Product_Family,"new business"=Final_category,customerstart=Date(2014,4,30),"include"=Disposition),1/(COUNTIFS(Product_Family,"Digital Core",Final_category,"new business",customerstart,DATE(2014,4,30),Disposition,"include",Customer_id,Customer_id)),0))}`

[Screenshot of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SScca.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution without using formulas would be to create a pivot table based on the data. Check "Add this data to the Data Model" when you create it and this will allow you to choose a **Distinct Count** value field setting. Set customer ID as the distinct count value and then set up the filters you want. With this method you can easily adjust the filters and refresh the pivot table as your data changes.

Comment: I can get to the distinct count using that but it will not give me a rollforward.
Begining balance + new business + expansion - contraction - churn = ending balance
 I am unable to use that option since i am using mac on excel unfortunately which does not have the "add to data model" thus can't do distinct count.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(K:K=41759),--(E:E="new business"),--(H:H="Digital Core"),--(F:F="include"),(B:B<>"")/COUNTIF(B:B,B:B&""))
```

Comment: `'=SUMPRODUCT(--(customerstart=41759),--(Final_category="new business"),--(Product_Family="Digital Core"),--(Disposition="include"),(Customer_id<>"")/COUNTIF(Customer_id,Customer_id&""))`


i used the formula but i am getting a count of zero still. Please advise where i went wrong.

I have used a variation of cell reference and the date formula for customer start date array.

Comment: Make sure all of your named ranges cover the same set of rows.